# Можно ли сказать: "за круглыми столами"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Правильно ли построено предложение: Участники за круглыми столами разработали и предложили на всеобщее обсуждение мероприятия на ближайший год. Меня смущает выражение "за круглыми столами".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласен, в таком виде не годится. Очевидно, имеется в виду формат обсуждения типа "круглый стол". И проблема здесь не только во множественном числе. Скажите: "в обсуждениях за круглыми столами участники..." и фразеологизм будет без труда распознаваться. Если всё равно останутся сомнения, можете взять словосочетание **за круглыми столами** в кавычки, подчёркивая не совсем привычное использование фразеологизма во множественном числе.

Пример из "Большой юридической энциклопедии":

> Считается, что именно в ходе неформальных дискуссий за круглыми
>   столами Давоса родились проекты НАФТА и ВТО.